# How to put expandable image into Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to "store" an image inside a small Excel cell, where I can double click that cell and the image will become temporarily viewable for further analysis.

One way to do that would be to upload the image to imgur and store a URL in the cell.

However, that would be rather tedious since I have the image on my desktop already and I don't wish to upload it to an intermediary.

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to uploading the image to a third-party website?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use hyperlinks to local disk files, rather than an online URL or intranet page. On the `insert link` dialogue, browse to your local file(s).

[image]

You can create the link to a file on disk, which would look something like this.

[image]

When you click the link, the file will open with your default viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Insert object directly go to **Insert** Tab- **Object**- **Create from File** and ***check*** **Display as icon**- **OK**:

[image]